# Can the question filter be extended to include a time frame?

Tags: feature-request, filtering

So we have this very nice filter on [/questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) (thanks for adding this btw!)

[image: Question Filter]

However I'd like it to be extended to be able to include a time frame. I'd specifically like to be able to exclude questions that have been added too recently.

Reason being it feels like most newly added questions are free-for-alls who can get the answer in there fastest, and it can be somewhat disheartening to write out a long answer with links to documentation, taking time to explain all nuance, only to return to the question to find someone has just dumped three lines of code in with no supporting info, been accepted and had 7 upvotes.

I'd essentially be using these free-for-all answerers to filter out the easy-to-answer noise by filtering to just unanswered, slightly aged questions.

Comment: But unfortunately these questions are mostly already answered in the comments, according to my experience... Maybe also a "no-comments"-field? ;)

Comment: You can always just use search to add a specific timespan, using either `created:` or `lastactive:`

Comment: BTW, you might be better off adding this as an answer on the [announcement, like this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/330356/194720).

Comment: *“it can be somewhat disheartening…”* Why? Play the long game, not the FGITW game. If you write a clearly better answer, as you described, then that’s worth posting, even if someone else has already fired off an acceptable answer. Your answer, being better, will surely get more upvotes over time, and even if it doesn’t, it’ll always be there to help future visitors. Remember that this site is not a help desk; we’re not just answering to help the original asker, so the fact that they’ve already accepted an answer is nearly irrelevant.

Comment: Oops, I posted a cross-site duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330536/218012